# How to get status of placed call on Amazon Connect?

Tags: python-3.x, boto3, amazon-connect

I'm writing an app which sends an automated call via Amazon Connect. The app needs to retry to another destination number should the first one fail to pick up. The app is being written in Python3 and is to be hosted in Lambda.

This is the resource is used 
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/connect.html#Connect.Client.get_contact_attributes
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/connect/latest/APIReference/API_GetContactAttributes.html

The problem is that "send call" is kicked off asynchronously and so it is not immediately clear if the call has succeeded or not. To check the call I invoke "get_contact_attributes" to identify status or any attributes which could point to the status of the placed call.

```
response=client.start_outbound_voice_contact(
    ContactFlowId='XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX',
    DestinationPhoneNumber=event["DestinationPhoneNumber"],
    SourcePhoneNumber=event["OriginationPhoneNumber"],
    InstanceId="YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY",
    Attributes={
        "message":f'{event["message"]}'
    }
)
contactid=response["ContactId"]

attr = client.get_contact_attributes(
    InstanceId='YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY',
    InitialContactId=contactid
)
```

I expected it to return "connected_at" or something like it I could use to identify the outcome of the call, however, it only returns "custom" attributes set by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the solution i found:

1) in the Contact Flow i added "Set Attribute" node where i set "status=1" right after the start. Basically, if a call enters Contact Flow (i.e. call picked up) it is marked as successfully completed

[Set Contact Sttributes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jEP1.png)

2) inside my Python code (lambda) i check for the status to show up and if it doesn't in so many seconds i cancel the call and try another number:

```
attr = client.get_contact_attributes(
    InstanceId=instanceid,
    InitialContactId=contactid
)

stop_call=client.stop_contact(
    ContactId=contactid,
    InstanceId=instanceid
)
```